# RNN: How to feed multiple different time series to the network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, forecasting, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm new to RNN's and asking for advice on how to feed data to an RNN such as a LSTM.

I'm trying to forecast wind speeds at one location. For this location i have historical values as a time series. Additionally I have multiple wind speed time series forecasts from a weather model at different locations which I want to feed to the network in order to make better predictions.

So I have values at my forecast location ranging from $T_{n-x}$ to $T_n$ where n is the current time and x is the number of past values. And forecast values at nearby locations ranging $T_{n}$ to $T_{n+y}$ where y is the forecast horizon. I hope this makes it clear...

How would you feed the data to a Network? Should I two RNN's for past and future time series and combine their output before making the final prediction?